# How to read position of html table and display in php mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Hello i have small project which is almost finished but the only thing remaining is setting the position of my widgets. I have 2 widgets Fahrzeuge and News.And at last i have 2 buttons Add Widget and Remove Widget which is functioning properly.When user try to add or remove widget i am updating position in database as 1 and 0.And now i want widget with postion 1 to display at top always and unable to do so.
Thank you.
Here is my database table :[image: table]
my complete html widget display from this code.I am taking the id of table and doing everything in ajax and javascript.And i want to display this table now according to position in database set:

```
$page['content'].='<table width="535" border="02>
<tr>
<td id ="Fahrzeuge">
</td>
</tr>
</table>';
$page['content'].='<table width="535" border="02>
<tr>
<td id ="News">
</td>
</tr>
</table>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this 
here am assuming you are using url like this

mynews.php?wid=1 or ?wid=0

```
    $wid_position = $_REQUEST['wid'];

    if($wid_position==''){
    $wid_position =1;
    }

select * from your_table where position=$wid_position
```

you can change the $wid_position value after clicking the widget Fahrzeuge  to news

Comment: Hi thank you but i cant change the url i have restriction ...i just trying proper select statement so that i chaneg

Comment: hi how you are sending request when you are clicking widget i mean ajax or .because there is no information about request

Comment: i am sending through ajax ...and i di not mentioned here because the code is large but its working ...the answer u told me its ok but how can i change my table postion from this query ?

Comment: in case of ajax your code might using a hidden value so make it 1 by default ,                          if not create a hidden variable provide id some thing like id="default_wid" and use that value to ajax request data area   
data: {wid:$('#default_wid').val()}

Comment: yes but i have two tables and everytime there position will change depending on user can add it or delete and the postion 1 with table alwys show at the top it will not work rht ? i have to use select query and then if condition thts it and there are i am doing wrong...

Comment: i agree ,but when ever you are working on add or delete ,change the hidden aswell